# Setting Up Windows Authentication for Apache

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2008, windows-authentication

To begin, I've been searching the internet for about an hour trying to find out how to do this with no success - therefore I'm writing this question.

I have an intranet site that requires to access the users Windows Username (not the server running Apache, but a user accessing the intranet site).

I have installed adLDAP and have it working where a user can log in by that, to check the group that the user is in. But, to have my site more secure I'd rather it access the Windows username.

I've saw that there's an apache module called mod_auth_sspi but I could not find how to install it or even implement (use) it in my code.

I am using Apache v2.4, PHP 5.6.8 on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: After a week of research I found out this tutorial https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/91377-implementing-single-sign-on-on-windows-with-apache This solves the problem with Apache 2.4. All the modules are attached in there. Just make sure you download all the DLL files and store it under respctive folders. Works like a charm for me

Comment: Anyone can shed some light if this is still valid in 2019?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So... I found out how to do this after a few more hours of Googling ... it should really be more straight forward to find an answer, but nevertheless, here it is:

1) Download the following module for your system (32 bit of 64 bit): https://www.apachehaus.net/modules/mod_authnz_sspi/

2) Paste the file into your modules folder. `/apache/modules/`

3) Edit the following configuration files:

3.1) `php/php.ini`: Uncomment `extension=php_ldap.dll` line.

3.2) `apache/conf/httpd.ini`: Add the following to the end of the LoadModules Section:

```
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authnz_sspi_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so
```

3.3) Find the `<Directory` tag and delete the opening and closing tag, along with its contents. Then paste in the following:

```
<Directory /> 
Options None 
AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
AuthName intranet
AuthType SSPI 
SSPIAuth On 
SSPIAuthoritative On 
SSPIOfferBasic On 
SSPIOmitDomain On 
Require valid-user 
</Directory>
```

Then after restarting Apache, it all should work. Obtain the user name of the Windows user via `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] ?>`

Comment: I unfortunately have followed all this and re-checked and double-checked my work and I still cannot get this to work.

Comment: @Lynchie In what scenario are you attempting to get this to work; in what way does it not work?

Comment: Hi Callum, Basically I want to get the Environment Username so that I can use it to control CSS Style Sheets.

Comment: @Lynchie I believe this only works via IE and Firefox?

Comment: I've tried this and Apache didn't start afterwards.

Comment: One setup step to note - be sure the build number vc_XX (e.g. vc_14) of the SSPI (mod_authnz_sspi) module matches the build number vc_XX version of the installed Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a much more detailed explanation I have which shows an Apache
server using LDAP authentication to Windows Domain Controller. And is using
NGINX to proxy requests to Apache... which manages authentication to IIS...
quite a complicated approach but NGINX is a much faster web proxy than Apache
in general.... these instructions are much more specific and likely accurate. Windows Server manages LDAP requests to Active Directory on Port 389 by default
this can be changed but at your own risk. Not many companies open 389 across public boundaries so you do need a web proxy usually.

note this configuration shows what you put above is not sufficient as I expected....

https://techexpert.tips/nginx/nginx-ldap-authentication-active-directory/

These are the additional Apache flags this team has identified which from experience looks accurate...

AuthBasicProvider ldap
Auth LDAPURL "ldap://10.X.X.X/CN=Users,DC=tech,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub(objectClass=*)"
AuthLDAPBindDN "bind@tech.local"
AuthLDAPBindPassword kamisama123