# How to use integrated windows authentication in php using LDAP

Tags: php, ldap, windows-authentication

I want to use windows authentication in my PHP project. I tried using the LDAP from this [link](http://I%20want%20to%20use%20windows%20authentication%20in%20my%20php%20project.%20I%20tried%20using%20the%20ldap%20from%20this%20[https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/using-ldap-active-directory-authentication-php]), But in this link html form is used. I want the windows login pop up for credentials. And how can I make switch to turn on or off windows authentication. Please provide the proper link or code

Comment: _"I want the windows login pop up for credentials"_ - What "windows login popup"? Are you talking about the browsers popup like on sites that uses http authentication?

Comment: ya exactly the default windows authentication

Comment: You can read how to trigger and use the browsers login popup 
[in PHP's manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). The first example should be pretty easy to use and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication is a feature of the web server, not the application framework. The web server handles the authentication and passes the verified credentials to the application. So it depends on which web server you're using. It will always be trickier on non-Windows servers, but it can be done.

For example, here are instructions I found for various web servers:

- [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34136128/1202807) (might be out of date, I don't know)
- [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html)
- [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/)

Then you can access the username in your PHP code using `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` or `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` (one of those - I don't know).

Browsers are capable of automatically sending the credentials of the currently logged on user account, if that's something you want. For Chrome and IE, the site has to be added to the Trusted Sites (in Internet Options). Firefox has [its own settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Integrated_authentication).

If you have trouble with it, let me know which web server and OS you're using.