# Invalid credentials while authenticating users on Active Directory with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

This is the first time I need to authenticate users on my PHP application with a remote Active Directory. I found a testing server on the web at [this link](https://www.zflexldapadministrator.com/index.php/blog/82-free-online-ldap) and wrote some codes to connect to the server and doing authentication in a testing mode:

```
$ldap_server = 'www.zflexldap.com';
$ldap_server_port = 389;
$ldap_username = 'guest1';
$ldap_password = 'guest1password';
$ldap_base_dn = 'ou=users,ou=guests,dc=zflexsoftware,dc=com';

$ldap_connection = ldap_connect($ldap_server, $ldap_server_port);

if ($ldap_connection === false) {
    echo 'Connection failed';
} else {
    echo 'Connected<br>';
}

ldap_set_option($ldap_connection , LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection , LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = ldap_bind($ldap_connection, 'uid='.$ldap_username.','.$ldap_base_dn, $ldap_password);
if ($bind) {
    echo 'Successful login';
} else {
    echo 'Failed login';
}
```

Result of executing this code is:

> Connected
> Successful login

After that, I created a real Active Directory Server on a virtual machine and defined users in this server as below:

[image]

And then, I changed the connection variables to these lines:

```
$ldap_server = 'SERVER_IP';
$ldap_server_port = 389;
$ldap_username = 'test1';
$ldap_password = 'test1_password';
$ldap_base_dn = 'ou=users,dc=website,dc=com'; // Imagine domain as website.com on AD
```

Now, while I want to connect to ldap server and authenticate the user `test1`, I am getting this result:

> Connected
> Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in index.php on line 25
> Failed login

I am sure that username and password are correct. I guess the issue might be on `base_dn`, but as I checked the server setting, I couldn't find any mistake on what I have written in my code.

May you help me to solve this issue please?

Comment: Are you running the PHP code on Windows or Linux? I ask because if you run PHP with IIS you can use integrated windows authentication in IIS to check the user against AD and then PHP can access their identity - far easier than the approach above.

Comment: @ADyson I am running the code on both Windows and Linux servers, but via Apache web server.

Comment: You should still be able to do as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/34136128/5947043 to get windows auth working with Apache. It's something you should do at the webserver level, not the application level. See also https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html

Comment: The issue is not about PHP modules. It works well as I mentioned about the first test. On the same web server which I had a successful authentication on server #1, I have the issue with the server #2.

Comment: You're misunderstanding me. I'm proposing a completely different (but far more conventional) approach, which wouldn't involve any of your code above, at all, just some configuration in your webserver.

Comment: @ADyson, my application should connect to a remote AD server. It is not a local connection, so I think have to use the code I wrote here.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `uid` with `sAMAccountName`? Besides I'd recommend checking the docs regarding `ldap_connect`.

Comment: @heiglandreas I don't know what is your idea about samAccountName, but I did it after reading your comment and did not achieve any result. By the way, the issue is not on `ldap_connect` as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to bind to LDAP you would use a distinguished name, which in case of Active Directory is not that easy to guess if you have any hierarchy in place. Your specific example would probably have DN of `CN=test1,CN=Users,DC=website,DC=com`. But if users are located in different OUs, it may be impossible to guess the DN and you would need a dedicated user to first find user's DN by his `sAMAccountName`.

However, with AD you can use user principal name to bind. This may be the value of `userPrincipalName` attribute, but it can also be an implicit UPN in the form of `user@domain`, so in your case `test1@website.com`. With this approach you don't need to know user's hierarchy, username (with domain) and password should be enough to bind.